# Not able to replace accurate rates MQL5

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

Here is the image of the custom symbol that I am trying to create:

[image: Image of the custom symbol.]

As you can see the values coming are not the values in the DATA section on MT5.

I am trying the following code for that purpose:

```
      ticks_array[0].time= StructToTime(running);
      ticks_array[0].bid = StringToDouble(s[7]);
      ticks_array[0].ask = StringToDouble(s[8]);
      ticks_array[0].last = StringToDouble(s[5]);
      ticks_array[0].flags= TICK_FLAG_LAST;

      ticks_array[Should_change].time_msc = 0; 
      CustomTicksAdd(symbol_custom,ticks_array);

      rates_add[0].time = Time_For_Rates;
      rates_add[0].open = StringToDouble(s[2]);
      rates_add[0].high= StringToDouble(s[3]);
      rates_add[0].low = StringToDouble(s[4]);
      rates_add[0].close=StringToDouble(s[5]);
      rates_add[0].spread=(int)((StringToDouble(s[8])-StringToDouble(s[7]))*10000);
      rates_add[0].tick_volume=StringToInteger(s[6])-1;
      rates_add[0].real_volume=0;      
      Print(CustomRatesReplace(symbol_custom,Time_For_Rates,Time_For_Rates,rates_add));
```

Please let know why is this happening and how i can resolve it.
**EDITED:**
Symbol configuration is: [uuu.json](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/388a7834632e5e74cde5d4145c3d810f)

Comment: Please can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

Price = StrToDouble(DoubleToStr(Price,5));

5 is your Digits. You can change it if you want

Comment: Thank you for your reply and my heartiest welcome on StackOverflow. Dear I have tried it but it helps in rounding the values. Whereas the API is sometimes throwing rounded values and sometimes not. That means I need some adoptive solution. Normalizing can be a solution but is not working like the adoptive one.

Comment: I will try it. I guess it still will not be what I am trying to achieve. But we never know until tried.... :)

Comment: Still I guess there is some issues with the MT5. It is adding extra numbers, don't know why

Comment: One question had you tried creating a custom symbol in MT5 before?

Comment: No i didn't. I edited my answer again. This new code should solve your problem

Comment: I know my friend, you are eager to give answer. But I have tried this before. It didn't worked, as the output what I an receiving is not away 5 digits, it is 6 or 7 or 5 sometimes and MT5 is not capable f converting it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a symbol - make sure you have enough digits. Your uuu.json says about 6 which is not correct - Digit is used to indicate number of digits after dot.

```
bool CustomSymbolSetInteger( "uuu", SYMBOL_DIGITS, 5);
```

No need to normalize (using `NormalizeDouble()`) if you have digits already.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I wanna go precise and my values are 6 digits. Hence, I have created a symbol with 6 digits.